# SQL - Display query data in table and sort by column on screen

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a huge table in my DB and I want to be able to display the contents and filter it by certain columns.

To do this I choose a filter which reloads the page and the sql query is rewritten with new conditions and parameters like so:

```
$params = [];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pricing";
if((isset($filter1) && $filter1!="") || (isset($filter2) && $filter2!="") || (isset($filter3) && $filter3!="") || (isset($filter4) && $filter4!="")){
    $sql .= " WHERE ";
}
if(isset($filter1) && $filter1!=""){
    $sql .= "supplier=?";
    array_push($params,$filter1);
}
if((isset($filter1) && $filter1!="") && ((isset($filter2) && $filter2!="") || (isset($filter3) && $filter3!="") || (isset($filter4) && $filter4!=""))){
    $sql .= " AND ";
}
if(isset($filter2) && $filter2!=""){
    $params1 = [$filter2];
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM product_categories WHERE category_id=?";
    $stmt = DB::run($sql1,$params1);
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $product_id = $row['product_id'];
        array_push($params,$product_id);
    }
    $sql .= "product=?";
    for($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
        $sql .= " OR product=?";
    }
}
if((isset($filter2) && $filter2!="") && ((isset($filter3) && $filter3!="") || (isset($filter4) && $filter4!=""))){
    $sql .= " AND ";
}
if(isset($filter3) && $filter3!=""){
    $params1 = ['%'.$filter3.'%'];
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? LIMIT 50";
    $stmt1 = DB::run($sql1,$params1);
    $count = $stmt1->rowCount();
    while($row = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $product_id = $row['id'];
        array_push($params,$product_id);
    }
    $sql .= "product=?";
    for($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
        $sql .= " OR product=?";
    }
}
if((isset($filter3) && $filter3!="") && (isset($filter4) && $filter4!="")){
    $sql .= " AND ";
}
if(isset($filter4) && $filter4!=""){
    $sql .= "model_no LIKE ?";
    array_push($params,'%'.$filter4.'%');
}
```

However this gets very complicated the more filters I want to add and doesn't necessarily work the best.

Is there any better options for sorting a table on screen? I'm not looking for a solution just a point in the right direction would be great, I've been searching for a while now but not finding what I am looking for.

Comment: use datatables on sort on the browser.

Comment: Instead of `isset($filter1) && $filter1!="")` just use `!empty($filter1)`.  Don't repeat checks on the same data, use nested condition blocks and potentially `elseif`.  There is much to fix/refine here.  Your question is also Too Broad.